# Entire site broken because of one custom module! No pages found anymore. How to fix?

Tags: 7

I wrote a custom module and implemented it.  Now I cannot access any pages on my drupal site.  They all say something like: Page not found.  The requested page "/" could not be found.

I removed the module by hand from the table by running:

```
UPDATE system SET status=0 WHERE name='MyModule';
```

Even with this, no pages are working anymore.  I thought it was an htaccess issue or a clean url issue, but even doing /?q=user does not get me to my login screen.  Any ideas on how implementing my one custom module broke the entire website?  My module was basically this:

```
function MyModule_menu() {
  $items['MyModule_views'] = array(
    'title' => 'MyModule test',
    'page callback' => 'MyModule_list',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => 'MENU_CALLBACK',
  );
  return $items;
}  

function MyModule_list() {
  return t('hello');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why your menu item above took over all paths, it should have only responded to paths that start with '/MyModule_view'. Maybe someone else can see what the problem is. However, I believe it's still causing problems because the menu registry hasn't been rebuilt. You'll need to clear that out to actually remove the menu item definition. Normally this would happen when you disable the module from 'admin/build/modules', but because you did this manually by altering the database that process didn't happen. If you use [Drush](http://drush.ws/) (which I highly recommend) you can rebuild the menu registry with

```
drush cc menu
```

If you don't have Drush, then you can write a simple script to rebuild the menu even though you can't really access your site. The script is explained in an answer over on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6912110/318158

Comment: THANK YOU!  I do not have drush, but the stackoverflow link you provided worked perfectly in writing my quick php script to have Drupal rebuild the menu.

Comment: It might be because the `type` is being set as a string instead of the constant val (should be `MENU_CALLBACK` not `'MENU_CALLBACK'`) but I'm not sure that would have such a big knock on effect

Comment: Nice catch though, didn't notice that at first. Could be related